# Проверить разделение массива возможен?

Tags: javascript

Дан массив A, и нужно понять можно массив разделить на две части, кажый из которых равен  10 -и или нет.

Например при случае 
A = [-2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 7]

Мы можем иметь эти две подмассивы [-2, 7, 5] и [5, 3, 2] сумма каждой из которых равен 10.

Нужно написать функцию которая получает массив и возвращает true или false в зависимости от того разделение массива возможен или нет.

```
  function permutDevide(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 1) {
        return false
    }

    if (sum(arr) != 20) {
        return false;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == 10) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(permutDevide([10, 5, 5])) // true
console.log(permutDevide([5, 3, 2, -1])) // false
console.log(permutDevide([-2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 7])) // true
console.log(permutDevide([7, 1, 3, 5, 2, 2])) //  true
console.log(permutDevide([1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 6])) // false  но должен возврощать true
```

Поможете решить задачу?

Comment: И что вы уже пытались сделать?

Comment: Я пытался разделить массив но нужны и перестановки нужны

Comment: function chunkArray(arr) {
    var i, j, tmp = [];
    for (i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i += arr.length / 2) {
        tmp.push(arr.slice(i, i + arr.length / 2));
    }
    return tmp;
}

Comment: Сначала проверь сумму чисел массива - может, она не 20... если всё в порядке - пытайся набрать десятку, вторая автоматически получится из остатка. Можно тупым перебором.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить такое решение! Алгоритм ниже:

**PS** спасибо @slippyk за исправление!

1. Если массив имеет внутри 10, ответ очевиден
2. Если нет, то находим сумму первых двух элементов, отнимаем 10 и смотрим какого значения, не хватает в данном массиве, чтобы получилось 10!
3. Если нет такого, то в зависимости от того какое значение (отрицательное или больше 10) рекурсивно суммируем дальше, формируя итоговую комбинацию!

```js
function sum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((sum, val) => {
        return sum + val
    }, 0)
}

function permutDevide(arr, need = 10) {
    if (arr.length == 1) {
        return false
    }

    if (sum(arr) != need * 2) {
        return false;
    }
    if (arr.includes(need)) return true;
    
    return checkArray(arr, arr[0], 1, need);
}

function checkArray(arr, current, index, need) {
  if (!arr[index]) return false;
  const firstSum = current + arr[index];
  const tempArr = arr.slice(index + 1, arr.length);
  if (firstSum >= 0) {
    if (tempArr.includes(Math.abs(need - firstSum))) return true;
    return checkArray(arr, firstSum, index + 1);
  }
  else {
    if (tempArr.includes(firstSum + need)) return true;
    return checkArray(arr, firstSum, index + 1);
  }
}
console.log(permutDevide([9, 3, 8]))
console.log(permutDevide([10, 5, 5]))
console.log(permutDevide([5, 3, 2, -1])) 
console.log(permutDevide([-2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 7])) 
console.log(permutDevide([7, 1, 3, 5, 2, 2])) 
console.log(permutDevide([1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 6]))
```

Comment: `всегда будет такая комбинация` - `[9, 3, 8]`

Comment: @slippyk кстати, да. Спасибо, о таком не подумал! + в карму. Уберу из ответа фразу